# HTML5 <video> jQuery conflict between click and mousedown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video

I have built a custom HTML5 UI, and am having some trouble with one aspect. There seems to be a conflict between `mousedown` and `click`, which is causing the 2 behaviours to fight against one another. All of the below jQuery functions work fine in isolation, but when I combine the `click` and `mousedown` event, this is where I am seeing the issue. The `click` event is intended to 'jump' the user to that part of the video. However, I also want the video to pause if a user is dragging the seekbar handle (or any part of the seekbar). At present, the `mousedown` function overrides the click function, resulting in a brief pause, but no updates to either the video or seekbar on click. Is there a way to make `click` and `mousedown` play nicely, to ensure I am able to `click` and drag the  as desired?

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/kaleidografik/pen/mYZJLM)

**HTML**

```
<video id="video" src="video-url.com" preload></video>
<div id="controls"></div>
<input id="seek-bar" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0" step="0.05">
```

**JQUERY**

```
// Video
var video = document.getElementById('video');
var controls = document.getElementById('controls');
var seekBar = document.getElementById('seek-bar');

// Controls
// Play/pause on video click
$(controls).on('click touchstart', function() {
  // If video is playing
  if ( video.paused === false ) {
    // Pause video
    video.pause();
  // If video is not playing
  } else {
    // Play video
    video.play();
  }
});

// Seek bar
// Update the video position when seekBar is changed
$(seekBar).on('change', function() {
  // Calculate the new time
  var time = video.duration * (seekBar.value / 100);
  // Update the video time
  video.currentTime = time;
});

// Update the video position when seekBar is clicked
$(seekBar).on('click', function() {
  // Calculate the new time
  var time = video.duration * (seekBar.value / 100);
  // Update the video time
  video.currentTime = time;
});

// Update the seekBar as the video plays
$(video).on('timeupdate', function() {
  // Calculate the seekBar value
  var value = (100 / video.duration) * video.currentTime;
  // Update the seekBar value
  seekBar.value = value;
});

// Pause the video when the slider handle is being dragged
$(seekBar).on('mousedown', function() {
  // Pause video
  video.pause();
});

// Play the video when the slider handle is dropped
$(seekBar).on('mouseup', function() {
  // Play video
  video.play();
});
```

Comment: This might help its working as you described: http://www.inwebson.com/html5/custom-html5-video-controls-with-jquery/

Comment: it seems like your mouseup event is dependent on your click event finishing, but they are both going to get fired simultaneously

Comment: You need to have the dragger graphic placed on one layer above the timeline bar/area. This way your users can click timeline bar to jump-to-time-X or else they can move dragger by drag-to-time-X. Have your click/drag code control the individual items themselves, not the entire one container itself `$(seekBar)` responds to two separate commands like click/drag.